# Best style for iterating through two lists in unison

Tags: java, list, coding-style, performance, iterator

Here is what I just wrote:

```
 public void mutate(){
    ListIterator<Double> git = genome.listIterator();
    Iterator<Double> mit = mutationStrategies.iterator();
    while (git.hasNext() && mit.hasNext()){
        git.set(alleleUpdate(git.next(), mit.next()));
    }

}
```

Is this the most efficient and clearest way of doing that? All that is necessary to know is that the genome list is setting its values according to some function that takes its current value and the current value of mutationStrategies. (If your into evolutionary stuff, this is for an Evolution Strategies algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to imagine how it could be tighter.  "Replace each git (whatever those are) with a mutated version of itself, stopping if we run out of mutation strategies."